# Passing complex object from angular service to MVC controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, httpservice

I am trying to pass complex object from angular service to MVC controller. Below is the code-:

**Angular Controller**

```
 $scope.saveData = function () {

 var resultData = new Object();
 resultData.Name = $scope.Name;
 resultData.Address = new Object();
 resultData.Address = $scope.Address;
 resultData.Address.Contact = $scope.Address.Contact;


     var promiseOrganization = AngularService.saveResult(resultData);

     promiseOrganization.then(function (result)
        {
            alert("Saved successfully.");
        }
    )
}
```

**Angular Service**

```
this.saveResult = function (resultData) {
    return $http.post("/Form/SaveData/" + resultData);
    }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string SaveData([FromBody] resultData data)
    {

        //operation to perform
        return "Data Reached";
    }
```

When I try passing complex object from Angular service to mvc controller. It gives me null i.e. object becomes null.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `$http.post` method you need to pass the data object as the second paramenter. You can read up on it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

[image]

So your angular code should look like

```
$http.post("/Form/SaveData/", data);
```

You then need a server side representation of the data you are passing the WebApi controller

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
   public string          Name    { get; set; }   
   public MyCustomAddress Address { get; set; } 
}

public class MyCustomAddress
{
   public string AddressLine1  { get; set; }
   public string AddressLine2  { get; set; }
   public string Contact       { get; set; }
}
```

You need to update your WebApi controller code to use the new server side class as the parameter. Note that I am not using the `[FromBody]` attribute as [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) link explains you only need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute when you want to force Web API to read a **simple** type from the request body(your type is a complex type)

> To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter

Updated WebApi Controller code **without** the `[FromBody]` attribute:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public string SaveData(MyCustomObject data)
{    
   //operation to perform
   return "Data Reached";
}
```

Comment: still geting null object at mvc controller end

Answer (score 0):

Change your post function to something like this,

```
$http.post('/Form/SaveData/', resultData)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in your post command. It should be:

```
$http.post("/Form/SaveData/",{resultData: resultData});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to add the following header -> `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

```
$http.post('/Form/SaveData/', resultData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});
```